# Batch for loop prints the same number multiple times

Tags: loops, batch-file, for-loop

I'd like to write a batch file which will display numbers from 1 to 5.
Here is my code:

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /l %%A in (1,1,5) do (
    SET number=%%A
    ECHO %number%
)
```

And here is an output:

```
5
5
5
5
5
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Actually you are getting the previous result as `number` is not initialised; upon the very first run, you'd receive `ECHO is on.` as `number` is empty at the time of expansion...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` and `!number!` instead of `%number%`.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /l %%A in (1,1,5) DO (
    SET number=%%A
    ECHO !number!
)
```

When variables are changed inside loop or if structures you always have to work with `ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` and access the variables as `!var!` instead of `%var%`.